# Drag and Drop getting image name iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, drag-and-drop

I have list of images in scroll view and four zone view(drop image View).I was implemented the drag and drop functionality.my problem was when user drag the image from scroll view i want get the image name or image id before or after drop the image. In my implementation i got only the image data. Any other way for getting image name or id value?

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: @Asaf I am using this library  https://github.com/martin-magakian/DragAndDrop-onZone

Comment: If you have an array of images, why don't you set a tag for each of element? So, basically, taping an element (select an image) should preserve the tag (id).